# Image Positioning OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

This may be called "Region of Interest" I'm not exactly sure. But, what I'd like to do is rather easy to explain.

I have a photo that I need to align to a grid.

https://snag.gy/YaAWdg.jpg

For starters; the little text that says "here" must be 151px from the top of the screen.

Next; from "here" to position 8 of the chin must be 631px

Finally; a straight line down the middle of the picture at line 28 on the nose must be done.

If i'm not making sense please tell me to elaborate.

I have the following ideas (this is pseudo code)

It is simply to loop until the requirements are met with a resize function, a lot like brute forcing but thats all i can think of..

i.e..

```
while (top.x,y = 151,0)
img.top-=1  ## this puts the image one pixel above until reaching the desired positioning
while (top.x,y & eight.x,y != 631)
resize += 1 # resize by 1 pixel until the height is reached
## center the nose
image.position = nose.
```

Comment: Take a pen and a piece of paper, draw it, and spend some time to work out the (elementary) math.

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching the order of your operations to prevent the need to iterate.  A little bit of math and a change of perspective should do the trick:

1.) [Resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) the image such that the distance from "here" to the chin is 631px.

2.) Use a [region of interest](https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-select-a-bounding-box-roi-in-opencv-cpp-python/) to crop your image so that "here" is 151px from the top of the screen.

3.) Draw your [line](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html).

**EDIT:**

The [affine transform in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html) would work to morph your image into the proper fill, assuming that you have all the proper constraints defined.

If all you need to do is a simple scale... First calculate the distance between points, using something like [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188/calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point/).

```
Point2f a(10,10);
Point2f b(100,100);

float euclideanDist(Point& p, Point& q) {
    Point diff = p - q;
    return cv::sqrt(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
}
```

Then create a scale factor to resize your image

```
float scaleFactor = euclideanDist(a,b) / 631;
cv::resize(input, output, cv::Size(), scaleFactor, scaleFactor, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

Using both instances of scaleFactor will create a uniform scaling in X&Y.  Using two different scale factors will scale X and Y independently.

Comment: There are a few approaches to step 1.  @I.Newton had one on his answer.  Alternatively use trig, find the distance btwn here and the point, and feed those parameters into resize.  Could you clarify your grid and setup?  Do you want a pure translation solution or do you want to "fill" the space, potentially distorting your image?

Comment: a basic resize will do. so i dont mind the distortion. my grid is like this.. 151 pix wihte space.... 631px head. rest of image, body. (that's what I need the result to be) otherwise, the image varies but i do have the top and bottom of head calculate as x,y values.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking at this point, but I updated the answer with a bit more detail.  Are these linear distances along a single axis (X or Y)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to OpenCV's tutorial, for images with faces you can use Haar Cascades to simplify the work. (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection)

Otherwise, look at ROI (Region of Interest) to extract an area and apply your algorithm on it (resize or crop)